# How to create a Power BI Embedded workspace with azure CLI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, azure-management-api, azure-cli

That is driving me insane.

*My main goal is to embed POWER BI reports/tiles in my Rails Web App.*

I have a POWER BI account with some reports. I have also created a Workspace collection on the Azure Portal for Power BI Embedded.

Through the portal **I can't** add a Workspace to my WorkspaceCollection (why M$?)

I'm working on OSX so **I can't** follow those instructions (PowerBI-embedded.sln in Visual Studio):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/

**So, as an alternative I'm using the OSX Azure CLI**:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/

After login I'm able to do this:

```
$ azure powerbi -h
help:    Commands to manage your Azure Power BI Embedded Workspace Collections
help:    
help:    Create a new workspace collection
help:      powerbi create [options] <resourceGroup> <name> <location> [tags]
help:    
help:    List workspace collections within subscription or within resource group
help:      powerbi list [options] [resourceGroup]
help:    
help:    Commands to manage your Power BI Workspace Collection keys
help:      powerbi keys list [options] <resourceGroup> <name>
help:      powerbi keys renew [options] <resourceGroup> <name>
help:    
help:    Commands to manage your Power BI Workspaces
help:      powerbi workspaces list [options] <resourceGroup> <name>
help:    
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help  output usage information
help:    
help:    Current Mode: arm (Azure Resource Management)
```

...and this:

```
$ azure powerbi list
info:    Executing command powerbi list
+ Getting workspace collections in subscription: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
data:    Name                         Group                  Location     Provisioning State  Tags
data:    ---------------------------  ---------------------  -----------  ------------------  ----
data:    MyCompanyWorkspaceCollection  MyCompanyResourceGroup  West Europe  Succeeded           null
data:    MyCompany-WC                  MyCompanyResourceGroup  West Europe  Succeeded           null
info:    powerbi list command OK
```

Great!

Now, how can I **provision a new Workspace** in my MyCompanyWorkspaceCollection (`Provision a new workspace in an existing workspace collection`)?

And After that, How to **import a PBIX file into that Workspace**?

Many thanks for your advices!

Comment: use powerbi-cli instead https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli

Comment: @CuongLe Thanks for sharing. I guess the xplat-cli-install is read only when it comes to PowerBI Embedded features...

Comment: Didn't work because of difference between OSX and Windows line endings.  Fortunately, stevenharman as posted 2 hacks here https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli/issues/5

Answer (score 5):

Thank you @CuongLe.

Hi,

To succeed I had to forgot everything I had read before... and start again with this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-iframe/

ON AZURE PORTAL
Create Power BI workspace collection, and get access key (Provisioning)

GET A PBIX
From Power BI Desktop or a sample file

WITH A CLI
(must use that one : https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Cli )
Create a Power BI workspace
Import .pbix file into the workspace
Get report id

IN MY RAILS APP
(using https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt )
Embed the report into the web page

I can't tell about the many bugs encountered, or the signup/login problems with Azure... it was really painful to get there.

Cheers everyone.